# Excel VBA: Macro for data processing getting slower and slower the longer it runs

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, large-data

I'm analysing large amounts of historical financial data using the QuantlibXl library in Excel 2010, 32-bit. My typical worksheet contains long columns of empirical data of up to 1 million rows. My macros usually need to to run through each row from the top to the bottom and do some Quantlib-typical financial analysis stuff like revaluing a security, which requires that Quantlib objects be created in every row. The analytical stuff is contained within the cells as formulas.

So in the beginning I tried to just select the cells with formulas in the top row and fill them down by dragging the lower right corner to the bottom of the sheet. Already here, the processing time grew exponentially with the number of rows involved.

So I figured I had to write a macro that processes smaller chunks of rows at one time. The macro would basically take care of filling down the top row only 100 rows at a time. That and a number of optimizations (explained below) certainly improved speed tremendously, but processing time still grew exponentially.

The problem is that as much as I try to optimize my macros, they keep getting slower and slower the longer they run. I keep track of processed rows in the status bar, and for example if 2000 rows are processed per minute (the calculations are pretty involved) when kick-starting the macro, its speed decreases constantly throughout its runtime, for example to only 100 rows per minute after 60,000 rows. At that rhythm, it will never see the end of the sheet. So in fact, at some point it becomes optimal to just abort it and start it off again from where it stopped. I also splitted the files and let them run on different computers simultaneouesly, which is a pain in the ass in terms of managing.

I already implemented tons of optimizations:
- screen updating and automatic calculations are turned off.
- I only perform calculation on the row being processed at a time.
- garbage collecting: Quantlib objects are deleted immediately after they are no longer used. I thought it was them eating all free memory that caused the slow-downs.
- I got so far to write the relevant results (cells) to a text file and delete the rows that were no longer needed. Again, the macro was very fast in the beginning and would have run until the end within a couple of hours if it wasn't getting slower again after like 70,000 rows. In fact, I had hoped to see a speed increase during runtime as rows are getting deleted and the sheet shrinks, but it just doesn't happen. So I just keep halting the process ever 60,000 rows and kick-starting it again, but its tiresome.

I'd like to figure out what causes this behaviour of Excel not processing large amounts of data linearly and requiring restarts, and how to avoid it. If somebody ran into similar trouble and found a way around it, I'd be glad to hear about it.

**EDIT:**  Every time I halt the process to speed it up again by starting over, I noticed that I have to restart Excel, otherwise it resumes just as slow as before. My current hypothesis is that at some point data isn't cleaned up correctly. If this is the case, your solution would bring me any further. The Quantlib library has a method to look at how many objects still reside in memory called ohRepositoryObjectCount(). I call the ohRepositoryDeleteAllObjects() function after every calculation and they are being effectively deleted as per that other method, but maybe there is still some leakage that remains undetected.

**EDIT2:** I'm now convinced there is memory leakage as after a long batch the task manager shows 3 or 4 Excel processes consuming together about 1.5 GB of memory. When quitting Excel, it crashes (with a message along the lines of "Excel is not working anymore"), and the processes persist, so I have to kill them manually.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what the issue is, but it would help to post some actual code.  Have you been monitoring memory usage in the longer runs - any chance you have a leak there which is causing the slow-down?

Comment: Memory usage of Excel during runtime ranges from 0.5 GB to 1 GB, nothing extraordinary even for the 32-bit version of Excel. I don't think if posting some code would help as most of the action takes place in QuantlibXl's XLL add-in.

Comment: Maybe its a problem with the quantlib library you are using. If you know your way around vba have you tried coding the functionality you need yourself?

Comment: Some of QuantlibXL's functions seem designed to update even if automatic calculation is turned off in Excel - see http://quantlib.org/quantlibxl/observer.html - and the use of permanent objects - detailed at http://quantlib.org/quantlibxl/references.html - can circumvent the usual garbage collection processes

Comment: @JMK: In fact, most cash flow discounting is quite basic and I have also already implemented it myself. But where Quantlib excels is at accounting for all kinds of market conventions, like how days are counted. Many professionals in finance use Quantlib just for this.

Comment: @barrowc: These are interesting points you raise and maybe I should ask for further advise within the quantlib community. However, I can rule out that my objects are permanent, as they are not by default and I do not instantiate them in that way. Also, memory consumption is not increasing noticeably during runtime. EDIT: looking at the reference again, it does not clearly say whether objects are permanent or not by default - will check more closely.

Comment: I checked again here and objects are non-permanent by default, see here http://quantlib.org/quantlibxl/references.html.

Comment: Deleting rows in excel 2007/2010 can cause huge performance hits. check to see if that is causing your issue

Comment: Earlier, I did without the deleting. It wasn't faster. When starting the macro, it is very fast, so I don't think the performance issues are related to these kinds of things that would rather have a constant effect on execution.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct, your rows are a listing of all your securities; and are not related to one another; and you don't calculate across them. If that is correct, do the following:

1. On a separate sheet, layout all your data columns (both input and
   output) to represent one row.
2. Copy and paste values one row of data from your "source" sheet.
3. Remove all your calculations from your source sheet and put it in here.
4. Copy and paste values back to your source sheet.

Put #2 to #4 into the macro and loop through your data.

That's my answer, the following are just commentary. If I were doing it:

1. my "source" data will be in a database. I'm sure there are relations
   among the securities that I would to explore.
2. I would transpose the row elements into a column on my calc sheet for easy reading.
3. I would break out the calculations across multiple columns and sections for easy reading.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. If I understand correctly, you would have a source worksheet (or database table) from which all required values for one calculation are copied to a "working" sheet where all the action takes place. I may try this, but don't think it will help any further. Every time I halt the process to speed it up again by starting over, I noticed that I have to restart Excel, otherwise it resumes just as slow as before. My current hypothesis is that at some point data isn't cleaned up correctly. If this is the case, your solution would bring me any further.

Comment: It has to do with the recalculation since you didn't "kill" the formulas by pasting values.

Comment: That's not true, in my early attempts I pasted values onto the cells with the formulas; later on I had the macro delete the rows with the formulas after the calculations. The main problem persisted. I guess this hints at a memory leak bug in the Quantlibxl library.